# Long path triggers error bash output ,if loop errror

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am getting an error while running the below code.
If I grep from $file1 then the script is not working.
If I grep from $file2 then the script is working.

both $file1 and $file2 having same permissions and same contents.But why I am receiving an error when I grep from $file1? Is there any syntax error here?

```
#./test.sh
./test.sh: line 23: $'true\r': command not found


$ cat /tmp/file.conf
random=true
abac
daccda
qwerty=
aewwrwr=false
```

script

```
file1="/app/some/directory/apache-tomcat-9.0.10/webapps/DESDv2.0/WEB-INF/classes/file.conf"
file2="/tmp/file.conf"

findfile=` grep "random" $file1 | awk -F = '{print $2}' `


if $findfile;then
echo "enabled";
else
echo "disabled";
fi
```

### Actual output

```
$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 23: $'true\r': command not found
```

### Expected output

```
$ ./test.sh
enabled
```

Comment: you have dos line endings. Fix with `dos2unix`. Inspect the files with `cat -v` or `hexdump -C`.

Comment: + you mix grep, awk and bash commands, you can do the same using a simple awk command : `awk 'BEGIN{random="disabled"}/random=true/{random="enabled"}END{print random}' <conf file>` . Fix dos2unix issues first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your file1 and file2 are different.  To check it, just type:

```
cksum $file1 $file2
```

They should produce same length and same checksum.  If not, they are different.

I further guess your two files have different line ending conventions:
file1 has DOS line endings (2 bytes line ending, i.e.  ), and file2 has Unix line ending (single byte line ending, i.e. ).

When you open them in an editor, they may appear to be the same.  In fact, the line ending representation is different.  Unix treats  the same way has other characters, and thus with this extra character, 'true' become 'true\r', and it cannot find a command named 'true\r'.